# Typescript extend a class method to an array of methods

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, inheritance, abstract

The basic idea is that I have an abstract class with a method that can be turned into an array of methods when extended by a subclass. The following is a working example but with workarounds:

```js
type ClassMethod = (food: string) => void
type ClassMethodArray = ClassMethod[]

abstract class Pet {
  // I would prefer this to be a ClassMethod instead of a ClassMethodArray with 1 entry...
  feed: ClassMethodArray = [
      (food) => console.log(`${food} was tasty!`)
  ]
}

class Cat extends Pet {}

class Dog extends Pet {
  feed: ClassMethodArray = [
      (food) => console.log(`1 ${food} is not enough...`),
      this.feed[0] // ...so that I can omit the [0] here...
  ]
}

// ...and here too
new Cat().feed[0]("cat treat")
new Dog().feed.forEach(func => func("dog treat"))
```

Output:

```
"cat treat was tasty!" 
"1 dog treat is not enough..." 
"dog treat was tasty!"
```

As described in the comments I would prefer if the abstract method in Pet is not an array with 1 entry but just a ClassMethod. And then in the derived class I can choose to let it be a method or extend it to a ClassMethodArray. Is that possible somehow?

Comment: Those types aren't compatible. 

How, through the types alone, should a programmer know whether any given Pet's `feed` method should be called directly or with forEach? For example, if I had a list of Pets and wanted to feed all of them, I would actually need to know their specific subclass which breaks the implementation.

Comment: @RyanSchaefer this will work because I will use this for an express router which accepts both a single method or an array of methods

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to extend the functionality of base class use can use `super` keyword in overridden implementation of the method:

```
type ClassMethod = (food: string) => void
type ClassMethodArray = ClassMethod[]

abstract class Pet {
  // base implementation
  feed(food: string) {
    console.log(`${food} was tasty!`)
  }
}

class Cat extends Pet {}

class Dog extends Pet {
  feed(food: string) {
    // custom behaviour
    console.log(`1 ${food} is not enough...`)
    // invoking the base implementation
    super.feed(food)
  }
}

new Cat().feed("cat treat")
new Dog().feed("dog treat")
```

Comment: I'm specifically looking to get an array of methods to pass to Express router middleware.